# How can I map cell value columns in two sheets to update an inventory column in second sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sync, microsoft-excel-2016

so I am exporting a csv of our websites full product inventory and need to import it to a secondary site that has a portion (not all) of the inventory, so to save time I would like to map the product SKU values in the column from both sheets, then when there is a match overwrite the Stock / Quantity value in sheet 2 respective columns. I've attached screenshots of both sheets to better understand.

I tried very hard to find this specific question already answered and could not find it so much thanks if you can! :)
BTW I'm not an Excel expert so please make the answer easy to understand for me and whoever is also searching for the solution.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: I believe you are looking for `INDEX/MATCH`

Comment: https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/index-match-formula-excel/

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't quite seem like it would work. Basically, I want to merge the sheets but have it only overwrite Quantity with Stock by matching SKU. The row positions will not be the same. So I could delete all columns but SKU and Stock, Quantity, then update sheet 2 by Stock overwriting Quantity. If there is a way to do this it would save me a massive amount of time.